# Implementar assertNotNull numa classe

Tags: java, junit, assert

estou estudando Testes Unitários e travei num teste. O contexto é de uma classe que identifica o tipo de triângulo, porém, nesse teste especificamente, preciso verificar se o método `tipoTriangulo` recebeu um parâmetro nulo, e caso receba, quero retornar uma mensagem de erro, para que na classe de testes eu consiga pegar ele e utilizar como teste.

Fui orientado a usar `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;` , mas ainda não consegui implementar por entender pouco de Junit. Podem me ajudar? Segue o código

```
public class identifica_triangulo{
public String tipoTriangulo(double x, double y, double z) {
    double a = y - z;
    double b = x - z;
    double c = x - y;

    identifica_triangulo triang = new identifica_triangulo();

    if (x == y && x == z && x != 0) {
        return "Três lados iguais . Trata-se de um Triângulo Equilatero";
    } else if (x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0) {
        return "O Triângulo não existe";
    } else if (x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0) {
        return "O Triângulo não existe";
    } else if (!(Math.abs(a) < x && x < y + z || Math.abs(b) < y && y < x + z || Math.abs(c) < z && z < x + y)) {
        return "O Triângulo não existe";
    } else if (x == y || x == z || y == z) {
        return "Dois lados iguais . Trata-se de um Triângulo Isosceles";
    } else
        return "Três lados diferentes. Trata-se de um Triângulo Escaleno";

}}
```

Comment: https://java2blog.com/junit-assertnotnull/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criar um teste unitário com o **JUnit** você deve importar essa biblioteca no seu projeto. Após isso você conseguirá utilizar a anotação `@Test` em algum método para sinalizar que se trata de um teste e as validações do `Assertions` como o `assertNotNull` e diversos outros.

Sobre seu teste de inserir um parâmetro nulo, não é possível de executar, porque você definiu que os parâmetros do método `tipoTriangulo` são *double* primitivo, ou seja, o método está esperando apenas esse tipo (double). Se você utilizar o objeto `Double` até consegue, porém ao executar será gerado uma exceção ao tentar subtrair um valor com outro vazio. O ideal seria você criar testes para todos os cenários propostos pelo if e else.

Exemplo de como ficaria um teste unitário usando `assertNotNull`:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class IdentificaTrianguloTest {

    private IdentificaTriangulo identificaTriangulo = new IdentificaTriangulo();

    @Test
    void quandoParametroNaoForNulo_deveRetornarValor() {
        String resultado = identificaTriangulo.tipoTriangulo(6.0, 5.5, 6.6);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(resultado);
    }
}
```

Pontos de atenção:

- Você não precisa instanciar o objeto `identifica_triangulo` dentro da própria classe, como fez na linha *identifica_triangulo triang = new identifica_triangulo()*. Instancie o objeto em outras classes e somente quando for necessário, e aí deste objeto então você poderá chamar o método `tipoTriangulo`.
- No java o nome das classes devem seguir o padrão [camel case](http://java-hunters.blogspot.com/2014/12/o-padrao-camelcase.html), assim sua classe ficaria `IdentificaTriangulo` em vez de `identifica_triangulo`, não que isso vá gerar um erro, é um padrão que comunidade Java utiliza.
- Outra boa prática é que para criar um teste unitário para determinada classe, crie outra **separada** com o mesmo nome, acrescido da palavra *Test*.
- Crie um teste para cada cenário de resultado possível do seu método. E utilize outras validações como `Assertions.assertEquals(resultadoEsperado, resultadoAtual)` para seu teste mais consistente.

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado pelos conselhos! Tentarei implementar.